# captcha does not load in spring

Tags: spring, jsp, captcha

i don't know why my captcha is not loaded in this jsp page! in my other jsp page it works good. i made it through a servlet. like this:

```
public class CaptchaServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        BufferedImage buffer =new BufferedImage(140, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = buffer.createGraphics();
        g.fillRect(1,1,138,48);
        Random rr = new Random();
        int x,y,r;
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        for(int i=0;i<119;i++) {
            x = 2+rr.nextInt(136);
            y = 2+rr.nextInt(46);
            r = 1+rr.nextInt(3);
            g.fillOval(x,y,r,r);
        }
        String str = "";
        String s = "";
        int n = 4 + rr.nextInt(3);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]");
        Matcher m;
        boolean found = false;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            m = p.matcher(s);
            while (!m.find()) {
                r = 65 + rr.nextInt(63);
                s = s.format("%c", r);
                m = p.matcher(s);
            }
            str = str + s;
            s = "";
        }

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute( "captcha", str );

        //TimesRoman Font.PLAIN SansSerif
        g.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 22));
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
            s = str.substring(i,i+1);
            x = 4+20*i+rr.nextInt(5);
            y = 20+rr.nextInt(20);
            g.drawString(s, x, y);
        }
        g.setXORMode(Color.white);
        for(int i=0;i<199;i++) {
            x = 2+rr.nextInt(136);
            y = 2+rr.nextInt(46);
            g.drawLine(x,y,x,y);
        }
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store"); //HTTP 1.1
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");        //HTTP 1.0
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
        response.setContentType("image/png");
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(buffer, "png", os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
}
```

and this is my jsp where captcha is called:

```
 <tr>
      <td><br/><img src="captcha-image.png"></td>
      <td style="margin-right: 5px;" valign="top"><br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Enter code
      <br><input type="text" name="captcha_text" value="" style="margin-left: 5px;"></td>
 </tr>
```

when i press `ctrl+b` on it, it goes to the servlet mapping correctly. but why it is not loaded? in another jsp it is working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it! when i viewed page source, the image source was pointing to `localhost:8080/votePoll/{id}/captcha-image.png` and not `localhost:8080/captcha-image.png` which it should be. i don't know why this happened because in my other jsp it wasn't so.

anyway, by changing image source to `localhost:8080/captcha-image.png` it worked fine!